# Is it easier to rank well in the search engines for one domain or multiple (related) domains?

Tags: seo

I plan to provide content/services across multiple (similar and related) subcategories. In general, users will only be interested in the one subcategory related to their needs.

Users will be searching for the term that would be part of the domain, subdomain or URL.

There's three possible strategies:

primary-domain.tld, with subdomains:

```
keyword-one.primary-domain.tld
keyword-two.primary-domain.tld
```

primary-domain.tld, with directories:

```
primary-domain.tld/keyword-one
primary-domain.tld/keyword-two
```

or each keyword gets its own domain:

```
keyword-one-foo.tld
keyword-two-foo.tld
```

From an SEO point of view, which is the best approach to take? I gather that having one overall domain would mean any links to any of the subdomains or directories weight for the whole site, helping the ranking of each subdomain/directory. However, supposedly if the domain, keywords and title all match nicely with the content, that would rank highly as well. So I'm unsure as to the best approach to take.

Comment: should be on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer I think anyone could give you here, is that you can't know.  Modern search engine algorithms are pretty sophisticated, and to know which marginally different naming methodology is better is impossible to know without inside knowledge.

Also even if you did know, it could change in the future.  Or perhaps it doesn't even come to the eqation at all, as it is open for abuse.

99% of the time it comes down to content.  Originality, quality etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you provide the best Quality Content and Make your website more SEO friendly, later domain names doesnot matter,

I personally prefer create several domains and maintain that, when the content grows, you can map it, this may help when you think of content Delivery networks.